# Javascript table with {{#each}}, filtering not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a table in which I want to make filtering functionality.

The table displays the records from meteor's collection through handlebars `{{#each}}`.

The code looks like this:

```
    keyup #filterbox': function(event){

      var table = document.getElementById('example');

      var len = table.rows.length;

      for(var i=1; i< table.rows.length; i++){

        var cellText = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML.toLowerCase();

        if(!(cellText.match(document.getElementById('filterbox').value.toLowerCase()))){

            table.rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        else{
            table.rows[i].style.display = "block";
        }               
      }
   };
```

The this code works when I type matching letters with predefined cell.

But when I clear the input box, the whole table gets collapsed. Only after I refresh the page it displays properly.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

`table.rows[i].style.display = "table-row";`

instead of

`table.rows[i].style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at a couple of plugins that would take care of the table sorting, filtering & paging. Its alot of work doing it from scratch.

- Tinytable http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/03/table-sorter/ - on meteorite as `teeble`
- Datatables (http://www.datatables.net/) - on meteorite as `datatables`

[Meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) is an unofficial community package manager.